# Installing QGIS 2.8 Wien on Windows 7?

Tags: qgis, installation, windows

Having trouble upgrading from QGIS 1.8, which ran just fine, to QGIS 2.8.

I'm running 64-bit Windows 7. After uninstalling QGIS 1.8, I've been trying for several days to install the 32-bit version of the QGIS 2.8 Standalone Installer.

The installer runs, but there's no program to start. The Start Menu folder is empty, and there is no `qgis.bat` in the directory that I installed to (C:\qgis). Trying to run `qgis-bin.exe` throws an error telling me that `qgis_core.dll` can't be found. The `postinstall.log` file has 15 instances of the error "System cannot find the path specified."

Any ideas?

Comment: It might help if you add the part of postinstall.log around where the first error message is stated.

Comment: I am having the same problem, no answers to solve it?

Comment: Welcome to GIS.SE. Please do not post questions/comments as answers.

Comment: I have this too. Weird that there is no answer to it.

Answer (score 3):

From my experience, there are 2 possibilities:

1. Have you tried to format your computer?
2. Have your tried to disable your anti-virus for the installation?

In the company I work, 4 computers installed it with no problems, but other 2 had exactly the same issues you described (running on 64-bit Windows 7).

We had to format these 2 computers, and after that the installation had no problems.

If you are in a network (like I am, at work), try installing with "Run as administrator" or calling the network manager to give your computer full permission to install softwares.

We didn't understand the problem though, maybe some messed up Microsoft's .NET Framework package.

Another thing we noticed, before we formatted the computers, the installation was too fast (it finished, but too fast), so I think something was blocking part of the installation without the installer noticing it (resulting in missing files like the `qgis_core.dll`).

Answer (score 1):

You can try alternative installer by NextGIS. Get it here: http://nextgis.com/nextgis-qgis/

See additional information here: http://nextgis.com/blog/qgis17/

[image]